# Get generic parameter of interface implementation

Tags: java

I have the following interface: `interface Nofifier<T> { }`.

I have the following implementation: `class MyClass implements Notifier<String>, Notifier<Integer> { }`.

Is there a way I can query from:

```
MyClass instance = new MyClass();
Class<?> clazz = instance.getClass();
// ...
```

to get the types of `Notifier` that `MyClass` implements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - you can call [`Class.getGenericInterfaces()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getGenericInterfaces--), which returns a `Type[]`. That includes type argument information.

Complete example:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

interface Notifier<T> { }

class Foo implements Notifier<String> {
}

class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Class<?> clazz = Foo.class;
       for (Type iface : clazz.getGenericInterfaces()) {
           System.out.println(iface);
       }
   }
}
```

However, you can't implement the same interface twice on one class anyway, so your `class MyClass implements Notifier<String>, Notifier<Integer>` shouldn't compile. You should get an error such as:

```
error: Notifier cannot be inherited with different arguments: 
    <java.lang.String> and <java.lang.Integer>
```

From [JLS 8.1.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.5):

> A class may not at the same time be a subtype of two interface types which are different parameterizations of the same generic interface (§9.1.2), or a subtype of a parameterization of a generic interface and a raw type naming that same generic interface, or a compile-time error occurs.